# General rule for using long

Tags: c++, c

I was told by an experienced programmer(spoj,codechef,topcoder etc ) than as a general rule one can use int for values upto 10^9.

What is the general rule for using 
signed long int,
unsigned long int,
signed long long int,
unsigned long long int

Comment: 4 byte int can store values up to 2^31 - 1 (by definition). I don't see a real question. you use a long when you need a long...

Comment: This is rather bad advice; while it will usually work on any real-world system you'll expect to encounter, it's not clear that you intend for the variable to be able to hold numbers in that particular range. Your types should be chosen for the range of values they need to store, and should be self-documenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your portability constraints.  Formally, an `int` is only
guaranteed to support values in the range `[-32767,32767]`, so anytime
you need more, you should use `long`.  Practically, a lot of programs
don't need portability to 16 bit machines (which are very rare today),
and on most modern 64 bit platforms, `long` will be 64 bits, which is
more than is needed, and will slow things down (if only because of 
poorer locality).  If you can assume `int` is at least 32 bits, that's
what you should use pretty much everywhere, with the following
exceptions:

- If you're concerned with the actual bitwise representation, using bitwise `&`, `|`, `^` and `~`, or the shifting operators, then you should use `unsigned` types, `unsigned int` by default, but other sizes if one of the following cases occurs.
- If you need the modulo arithmetic of `unsigned`, use an unsigned type.  This is very, very rare, but does occur in things like calculating hash
  codes.
- If you have really large tables (vectors or any other contiguous representation), you might consider `short` or even `signed char` (or `unsigned short` or `unsigned char`, if you're concerned with the bitwise representation).  I would *not* use plain `char` for anything but characters, since its signedness is implementation defined.
- If you need to represent values greater than 2^31, then consider `long long`.  (Often, however, even `long long` won't be big enough in such cases, and you'll need some sort of `BigInteger` class.)

As a general rule, anything but `int` should be the exception.

Comment: This answer is right on everything but the last sentence, which reflects a really outdated, unsafe programming style. You should always use `size_t` for anything that represents a size or count of array members, including most loop indices. You should also (if you're on a system where they are available, i.e. anything POSIX) use `off_t` for file sizes/offsets, which could definitely be larger than `int` or even `long`.

Comment: @R `size_t` is not for general use; it must be unsigned, and unsigned in C++ is broken for numerical values.  For things like offsets in a file, I agree.  You should use a typedef (but to a signed type---`off_t` is traditionally signed, although Posix doesn't even require it to be a numeric type).  But that falls in one of the exceptions I mentioned: you probably _do_ need to exceed 2^31.

Comment: You are wrong there. `off_t` is a signed integer type per POSIX. I think you're confusing it with the (useless) `fpos_t` in standard C. As for `size_t` being unsigned, would you care to elaborate on how that's "broken"?

Comment: @R I can't find where Posix sets any real requirements for `off_t`, but traditionally, it was a typedef to `long`, and you could "back-up" in a file with something like `lseek(fd, -10, SEEK_CUR)`.  (This is what current Linux does as well.)

Comment: @R The unsigned types in C (and C++) are broken _if_ you try to use them for countable things.  If you have two counts, `abs( a - b )` should give the distance between them.  If it doesn't, then the type isn't appropriate.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html "blkcnt_t and off_t shall be signed integer types."

Comment: I find your requirement that you be able to take the absolute value of  differences rather arbitrary; it's **never** safe to take sums or differences in C or C++ without consideration of overflow (for signed) or wrapping (for unsigned). And the `abs` function is near-useless, as it invokes UB for `INT_MIN`. As long as you are taking care of these issues correctly, you can compute the absolute difference between unsigned in all cases; for signed values, it's often impossible to compute the absolute difference in the same type.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12419/discussion-between-james-kanze-and-r)

Comment: @R You don't seem to understand the important of validating input before using it.  The `abs` function is very usable, for values within range.  And you validate all input to ensure that all values will be in range before doing anything else.  This is a fundamental of just about any programming---inputs are always validated, immediately.

Comment: I think that's what I just said... but instead of having error cases for values that are **not invalid**, just far apart, I'd want to switch to an unsigned (or larger signed) type for the absolute difference.

Comment: @R You may need a larger type than `int` in certain cases (although for the length of a string, I doubt it).  But as long as the type is holding arithmetic values, you should avoid unsigned types.

Comment: You haven't presented any evidence for your claim. Signed and unsigned types both have a number of advantages and disadvantages that you have to weigh. The most important thing is being conscious of the types you're using and making sure that the values fit, as opposed to blindly using one or two types with no attention to whether they are appropriate.

Comment: I agree that you usually don't *want* a string whose length is too long to fit in `int`. The problem is that you might have to deal with getting one from somebody who gave it to you in the hopes that you were stupid and didn't anticipate getting it. And if it's a C sting, there's no efficient way to test that its length fits in `int` before processing it.

Comment: @R You mean you've ignored the evidence I presented.  Subtraction (and comparison with signed values) doesn't work correctly with unsigned types.  It's best to avoid them for arithmetic values.

Comment: @R If you receive a C style string from elsewhere, you can easily validate its length using `strlen`.  It's not difficult to write `if (strlen(s) > INT_MAX)`, or whatever.

Comment: That's an extremely expensive operation. In particular it can invalidate the entire L1 and L2 cache even for reasonable-length strings.

Comment: As for subtraction, it doesn't work "correctly" with signed types either, and the result is even worse (undefined behavior). If you want to subtract, you need to do extra work, whichever types you use.

Comment: @R But you have to do it anyway.  (It's a basic failing of C style strings, and why no one uses them for anything but very short strings.)

Comment: @R As I've said, you _validate_ your input, so you don't have problems with overflow.  In the case of unsigned, you'll get an incorrect answer without overflow, and there's no way you can validate the input, because you can get it with any possible value.

Comment: If your goal is to take an absolute difference, you can always do it with unsigned; the same is not true with signed. If you want a signed difference, it's not going to be possible unless your values are in a limited range; this is true of both signed and unsigned types.

Comment: @R If your goal is for arithmetic to work correctly, within a previously limited range, you can do it with signed types.  You can't do it with unsigned.

Comment: Regarding strings, you do not have to call `strlen` "anyway"; a large portion of the operations you perform on strings access the string sequentially from the beginning and do not need to process the whole string. This is especially the case in parsing, etc.

Comment: @R But then you don't care whether the length fits into an `int` or not.

Comment: Yes you do. If you use an `int` to store your working position in the string, your code will crash if someone passes you a maliciously long string and your counter overflows and tries to index `str[INT_MIN]` (or actually anything, since the overflow is UB).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12419/discussion-between-james-kanze-and-r)

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is platform dependent (because different platforms may have different sizes of integers). You can find a fairly complete list of limits at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

Answer (score 3):

The main time to use `int` and `long` is when you're interfacing with an API that uses these types. For instance, error codes and file descriptors have type `int` and `ftell` returns `long`. You can also use `int` for indices/counters when you know the numbers you'll be dealing with are very small and bounded (i.e. can't grow proportionate to something outside your full control). Otherwise, you should always be using `size_t` for sizes/indices/counts of objects in memory, and exact- or at-least size types from `stdint.h` when you need to be able to store values of particular known magnitudes.

If you can't use `stdint.h` (for instance, on C89 or old C++ implementations), you can instead make use of the plain old types:

1. `short` can store at least the range -32767 to 32767.
2. `unsigned short` can store at least the range 0 to 65536.
3. `int` can store at least the range -32767 to 32767 (and -2147483647 to 2147483647 on POSIX conforming systems).
4. `unsigned` can store at least the range 0 to 65536 (and 0 to 4294967295 on POSIX conforming systems).
5. `long` can store at least the range -2147483647 to 2147483647.
6. `unsigned long` can store at least the range 0 to 4294967295.

Comment: As a general rule, types like `size_t` and the types in `stdint.h` are for special use, and should rarely appear.  Unless you have special requirements (and interfacing to an external API is one), the best practice is to just stick with `int`.

Comment: @James: That's simply wrong. Any time you're dealing with sizes in memory that can come from somewhere you don't have full control over (e.g. the the length of a string passed in by a caller), you **must** use `size_t`. Using `int` will result in truncation and almost always translates to a security compromise, although it may be hard to trigger.

Comment: @R That's simply false.  Whether you use `size_t` or `int` changes absolutely nothing in this respect.  If the string is too long, you'll get an `std::bad_alloc` at some point.

Comment: Nope. Suppose the input string is 0x100001000 bytes long. Truncating `strlen` to `int` before making a working copy will result in only allocating 0x1000 bytes. Have fun calling `strcpy` then...

Comment: If you're input string is 0x100001000 bytes long, on a 32 bit machine, you'll get `std::bad_alloc` when you try to read it.  To be on the safe side, however, you might compare the size immediately after reading it, to ensure that it's not too big to handle.  The constant you use in the comparison will doubtlessly have type `int`,  but you can compare an `int` with the type of `size_t`.  (Generally, regardless of the type of input, you need to validate it immediately, to ensure that there will not be overflows downstream.)

Comment: You continue to misunderstand the situation. Your first statement is blatantly incorrect; attempting to allocate that much on a 32-bit machine cannot give an error because you cannot attempt to allocate that much in the first place; the type cannot represent the value. In any case, if you write `int len = strlen(str); char *str2 = malloc(len+1); strcpy(str2, str);` then you have a serious bug/vuln.

Comment: By the way, using the wrong type (`int` for sizes) was the cause of the infamous qmail remote vuln that DJB refused to acknowledge or fix, despite his bug bounty on qmail. It's a **serious** programming error.

Comment: @R I perfectly understand the situation; I've been working on critical systems for over 30 years.  And when I try to read a string which is too long to fit in the available memory, I get an `std::bad_alloc` exception (as is required by the standard).  (And I haven't used `strlen` since I switched to C++.  Which was before `size_t` existed, and when `strlen` returned an `int`.  But the code you write isn't an error, _if_ you've programmed the rest correctly, so that you can't have strings longer than `INT_MAX`. (On many systems, e.g. Windows, the OS won't allow it.)

Comment: What you're describing is safe if you wrote all the code yourself and used `int` (wrongly) everywhere, and thereby know you never have any objects larger than `INT_MAX`. However, if you want to integrate your code with any other code, then everywhere it gets a string from code that's not under your control, you're going to have to call `strlen` on that string and make sure the length fits in `int`, or else you have a potential vulnerability somewhere down the line. `size_t` exists for a reason. Use it. "I've been doing it this way for 30 years" is not a good reason.

Comment: @R If you're getting strings from elsewhere, then you have to validate them.  That's rather obvious.  And the maximum length you accept will almost certainly be significantly less than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Calling `strlen` (O(n)) on each string before you do anything with it is a nasty cost. For example if you're going to search it for a substring or parse a number out of it, you'd like to avoid reading any more than you have to, because in many cases you'll find the result right away. If your code is robust to any possible input string size (i.e. using `size_t` for the position in the string) then you don't need to precompute length; you just go. It makes your code both simple and faster.

Comment: @R Nasty or not, if you're going to use the string, you have to do it.  (Generally, of course, _you_ don't do it.  You pass the `char*` to `std::string`, and `std::string` does it.  Possibly resulting in an `std::bad_alloc`.)

Comment: No. On a 64-bit machine, you can easily make a 3-, 4-, or 100-GB `std::string`, assuming you have sufficient memory for it. Of course if you're converting a possibly-large C string to a C++ one before even doing any work on it, your program is going to be slow as hell already (always incurring the O(n) penalty). Note that this question was tagged both C and C++, and in idiomatic C you certainly would not copy a string to perform read-only operations on it.

Comment: @R You can, but would you?  You don't have to.  If it would be useful, then of course, you'll use `long long` instead of `int`.  But such cases are surely the exception.

Comment: No, it would be `size_t`, not `long long`. The type for sizes of objects is always `size_t`. And the point is not that you would intentionally do it, but that unexpected input would do it for the sake of exploiting a vulnerability in your program.

Comment: @R The problem is that `size_t` is unsigned, so you almost never want to use it.  You check first that the length of any string you input is within the range of lengths you can accept (which should typically be considerably less than `INT_MAX`---any string that long is probably an attempted attack), and you don't use unsigned types for numerical values, because they don't work for numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

You can open up `limits.h` and infer rules by yourself:

```
#define LONG_MIN    (-2147483647L - 1) /* minimum (signed) long value */
#define LONG_MAX      2147483647L   /* maximum (signed) long value */
#define ULONG_MAX     0xffffffffUL  /* maximum unsigned long value */
#define LLONG_MAX     9223372036854775807i64       /* maximum signed long long int value */
#define LLONG_MIN   (-9223372036854775807i64 - 1)  /* minimum signed long long int value */
#define ULLONG_MAX    0xffffffffffffffffui64       /* maximum unsigned long long int value */
```

Comment: Looking at the definitions on one implementation does not answer the question about how to write good C code...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which libc you are using, there are generally macros which will tell you the limiting values of an `int`, `long int`, etc.  For a portable example, look at the limit macros provided by [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Limits-of-Basic-Types.html).

Answer (score 0):

you may want to take a look in the standard header [climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/) or limits.h

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, for any of the types which are signed, if the type size is n bits, then

```
Max Positive Value = 2^(n-1)-1 <br>
Max Negative Value = -2^(n-1)
```

Again each platforms might have variations and you should refer to the limits.h available in that platform for getting the exact values.